# Pythonic way of writing a sequence of integers in monotonically increasing order

Tags: python

What is the pythonic and efficient way of writing integers from `1` to `10**6` where digits are in a monotonically increasing order?

For example:
`(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,20,21,22,30,31,32,33,...)`

This gets the job done but looks pretty ugly.

```
nums = [10**0*k6 for k6 in range(1,10)] +
       [10**1*k5 + 10**0*k6 for k5 in range(1,10) for k6 in range(k5+1)] + 
       [10**2*k4 + 10**1*k5 + 10**0*k6 
        for k4 in range(1,10) for k5 in range(k4+1) for k6 in range(k5+1)] +
       [10**3*k3 + 10**2*k4 + 10**1*k5 + 10**0*k6
        for k3 in range(1,10) for k4 in range(k3+1) for k5 in range(k4+1) for k6 in range(k5+1)] +
       [10**4*k2 + 10**3*k3 + 10**2*k4 + 10**1*k5 + 10**0*k6
        for k2 in range(1,10) for k3 in range(k2+1) for k4 in range(k3+1) for k5 in range(k4+1) for k6 in range(k5+1)] +
       [10**5*k1 + 10**4*k2 + 10**3*k3 + 10**2*k4 + 10**1*k5 + 10**0*k6
        for k1 in range(1,10) for k2 in range(k1+1) for k3 in range(k2+1) for k4 in range(k3+1) for k5 in range(k4+1) for k6 in range(k5+1)]
```

Comment: what do you mean non-decreasing order?

Comment: `non-decreasing == ascending` ?

Comment: It's supposed to say non-increasing

Comment: I think he means having a number `(d1)(d2)(d3)...` each digit `(dn)` must be greater than or equal to `(dn-1)`

Comment: Could you provide a concise example of input and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns 8001 numbers for `max_digits=6`:

```
def ascending(ndig, first_digit_max):
    for x in range(0, first_digit_max+1):
        if ndig == 1:
            yield [x]
        else:
            for y in ascending(ndig-1, x):
                yield [x] + y

max_digits = 6
nums = sorted([int(''.join(map(str, num)))
               for ndig in range(1, max_digits+1)
               for num in ascending(ndig, 9)
               if any(num)])
```

`ascending` yields lists of `ndig` digits, where the first digit is lower or equal to `first_digit_max`. It works recursively, so if it is called with `ndig=6`, it calls itself with `ndig=5`, etc. until it calls itself with `ndig=1` where it returns just individual digits. These are lists, so they have to be checked if any of these digits is different to zero (otherwise it would return 0, 00, 000, etc. as well) and converted into numbers.

Comment: I'd appreciate a quick overview of the logic behind this solution :)

Comment: Quite smart to use recursion for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
def gen(size_digits):
        if size_digits == 0:
            return ( i  for i in range(10) ) 
        else:
            return ( new_dig*(10**size_digits) + old_digit  for old_digit in gen(size_digits-1) for new_dig in range(10) if  new_dig <  int(str(old_digit)[0])   )



l = [ num for num in gen(6) ]
```

Comment: A few improvements: find the most-significant digit of `old_digit` with `old_digit/10**(size_digits-1)`. Or alternatively, pass `new_dig` to your recursive call (in an optional argument, defaulting to 9) and make the `range` calls go to that `arg+1` (then you don't need the `if` in the generator expression at all).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an (almost) one-liner:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from string import digits

lst = sorted(set(int('0' + ''.join(reversed(e))) 
             for e in combinations_with_replacement([''] + list(digits), 6)))[1:]    
print lst
```

---

**How it works**

`digits` is the string `0123456789` and `combinations_with_replacement` creates every combination of *sorted digits* that's possible. By adding the empty string, we get every sorted integer of size less or equal to 6.

Of course, we want the digits in reverse sorted orde, not sorted order, so that's why we reverse each result. But this puts the list out order, so we sort the result.

Also, our trick with the empty string causes a few duplicates to get included (not very many) so we use set() to get rid of them.

Comment: Yes, all the ones that meet the requirement of having non-decreasing digits.

Comment: It doesn't include values with fewer than six digits though (except for `0`, which should be skipped). That is, `1` won't be included because in a six-digit form, `000001` is not non-increasing.

Comment: `set` takes an iterator as well, so you can drop the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

*Just doing it* might end up being more efficient (performance-wise):

```
def xfn():
    x, i = [9], 0

    while True:
        if i == len(x) - 1:
            x.insert(i, 0)

        if x[i] < x[i+1]:
            x[i] += 1
            x[0:i] = [0] * i
            i -= 1
            yield int(''.join(map(str, reversed(x[0:-1]))))
            continue

        i += 1

itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < 10 ** 6, xfn())
```

Answer (score 0):

How efficient do you want to be?

```
[i for i in range(10**6) if str(i) == ''.join(sorted(str(i), reverse=True))]
```

Using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from string import digits
sorted(int(''.join(reversed(t)))
       for n in range(6)
       for t in combinations_with_replacement(digits, n)
       if not all(d == '0' for d in t))
```

Comment: I think the standard answer to that is, "more efficient than the brute force approach" :P

Comment: Would already be quite a bit faster if you write a simple O(n) function rather than using `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

I've not quite figured out *why* this works, but the intended method is to take a digit, and append it to all the numbers we've already generated that it can fit with - which can be decided by looking at the rightmost digit of the number.

```
length = 6

digits = range(10)

numbers = digits[1:]
for curNumber in numbers:
    for n in range(1 + curNumber%10):
        numbers.append(curNumber*10 + n)
    if(curNumber == 99999):
        break

print numbers
```